# Integrating Maximo with Mapinfo?

Tags: mapinfo

I am software developer and have been working on database 
and Java as major platform for development. I am using Mapinfo for GIS analysis.
Now, the system needs to show trouble tickets in Mapinfo that are achieved from 
Maximo software. How is it possible to connect these two application?

Comment: We have had some luck with our own product that bolts onto ArcGIS Server.  Will be interested to see how you get on with Mapinfo.  You aiming to use MapBasic to create the tool?

Comment: @Simon yes but I am not sure how to get started. Would you share your experience? :)

Comment: If Maximo stored it's information/data in a database, you should be able to access this information there.

Comment: @Peter I am not given access to database directly but I have access to NMS(network management System) which acts as source of data.

Comment: @Kitex: Maximo depends on having a spatial solution to join its tickets to; do you have a existing layer of points or assets that you can join to for the Maximo Data? I have done a lot with Maximo and a lot depends on what you are connecting it too.

Comment: @D.E.Wright I have layer of points representing various Network Element on mapinfo but I haven't done much with maximo.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed a Maximo 7.5 interface to Bing Maps using the interface and properties application. The gps coordinates are stored in the location table.

I have the maps on the startcenter showing workorders. On the location app showing locations and the assets app. The app coordinates can be batch uploaded or dynamic.

The solution is modular and be installed in just a few hours.